# would Bootstrap "col" classes work with other HTML tags than div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I was wondering what would be the best practice of using the "col" classes in Bootstrap.

**example 1** - I already know this way is valid

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1> Heading</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**example 2** - would this be considered a good practice as well?

```
 <div class="row">
    <h1 class="col-12"> Heading</h1>    
</div>
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: In my opinion, and based on some experience, sometimes the second option don't work as expected. So I will ever use the first option. You should check what style the `col-*` adds to be sure they don't conflict with other elements when you go with the second option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Grid System documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) includes only examples with `div` elements, and although the CSS styling applied by Bootstrap is not limited by any tag but only by classes (e.g. `.col-md-6` instead of `div.col-md-6`) it is a better approach to nest your content in a `div`, for at least two reasons:

- It will allow you to add other content later to the same column, such as a button or tooltip after the heading
- Allows better styling of your `h1` tag, and does not apply the automatic gutter of 15px on each side of it, which can make your heading alignment incoherent

Having said that, there may be more complex cases where your second approach would benefit, but in this case it does not seem applicable.

Comment: Thank you @Siavas. It makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the grid with other elements too as it is classes , but try to follow standards of coding and styling for proper code management and readability.
according to which example 1 is correct way

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
      <h1> Heading</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @cyrus. unfortunately I can pick only one answer but your answer is very much helpful.

Comment: its ok no problem